# Using R to extract data from Global Aridity Index and Potential Evapotranspiration (ET0) Climate Database v2?

Tags: raster, r

I have a latitude/longitude [dataset](https://figshare.com/articles/Global_Aridity_Index_and_Potential_Evapotranspiration_ET0_Climate_Database_v2/7504448/3); I wish to extract the aridity index for each of location in R.

I am new to R, so I seek basic code along with the required libraries.

Comment: Can you give a link to this database?

Comment: https://figshare.com/articles/Global_Aridity_Index_and_Potential_Evapotranspiration_ET0_Climate_Database_v2/7504448/3

Comment: What do you mean by "each of location"?

Comment: This is quite a broad question, especially since you say you seek basic code. Usually basic code is well-documented elsewhere and we dont want to repeat that here. Have you studied any R spatial tutorials? You should be able to learn most of what you need for this problem from them - reading spatial data, sampling points from grids etc.

Answer (score 1):

@Gagandeep Singh use raster::extract() to do so. ATTENTION: make sure you are using two datasets with the same crs via sp::identicalCRS()!

URL:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.9-23/topics/extract

```
raster1 <- raster()
# load specific raster-dataset (in your case global aridity index, ...)
coords <- readOGR()
# load the spatial points where you want to extract the data from the raster datasets

identicalCRS(raster1, coords)
# check for the crs

point_data <- extract(raster1, coords)
# extract the data. ATTENTION: you can use different methods, buffer, ... specify that via additional arguments
```